# I am having a problem with my login page. using sqlite database

Tags: vb.net

below is my login code:

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        cn = New SQLiteConnection
        Try
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserLogin WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME And PASSWORD= @PASSWORD"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", txtUser.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", txtPass.Text)
                Dim reader = cm.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read
                    Home.btnstudent.Enabled = True
                    Home.btnlis.Enabled = True
                    Home.btnsubject.Enabled = True
                    Home.btntrans.Enabled = True
                    Home.btnmStudent.Enabled = True
                    Home.btnuser.Enabled = True
                    MessageBox.Show("You are welcome")
                    UserValid = True
                End While
                If UserValid = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("sorry, Access denied", "Incorrect Password!")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZgiT.png)

Comment: *I am having a problem* is not a useful problem description without details. What specific problem are you having? You've dumped a bunch of code, added a useless image that does not show a problem of any sort, not explained any problem at all, and not asked a question at all. Please see [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question. We're more than happy to help, but you have to do your part first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't us .AddWithValue. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

All you need is the count to see if this is a valid user. Don't retrieve data unnecessarily.

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim count As Integer
    Using cn = New SQLiteConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cm As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM UserLogin WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME And PASSWORD= @PASSWORD", cn)
            cm.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", DbType.String).Value = txtUser.Text
            cm.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", DbType.String).Value = txtPass.Text
            Try
                cn.Open()
                count = CInt(cm.ExecuteScalar)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using 'Closes and disposes command
    End Using 'Closes and disposes connection
    'Do all this AFTER the connection and command are closed and disposed
    'Showing a message box while your connection is open can keep the connection open
    'until your user gets back from lunch and clicks OK
    If count = 1 Then
        Home.btnstudent.Enabled = True
        Home.btnlis.Enabled = True
        Home.btnsubject.Enabled = True
        Home.btntrans.Enabled = True
        Home.btnmStudent.Enabled = True
        Home.btnuser.Enabled = True
        MessageBox.Show("You are welcome")
        UserValid = True
    Else
        'Don't tell the user exactly what was wrong with their login.
        MessageBox.Show("sorry, Access denied", "Invalid Login")
    End If

End Sub
```